# Unity 2D object not moving

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I'm trying to build something by learning Unity, but I have a problem. I'm trying to make a simple 2D Brick Breaking Game but I had to stop at the beginning because the object doesn't move. I did research, etc., but I couldn't come to a conclusion. When I made a solution with the rigidbody, the object moved up and down, but I want it to move left and right to start. I'll be sharing the code as well. To add, the paddle in Unity is not static vs. and doesn't seem to have any problems. When I call the update function Debug.Log, I can see the console on Unity when I write in it. Can you help?

Also my unity screen is below. I dont know what i am missing.
[My Unity Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9RJWf.png)

```
public class PaddleController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    float speed;

    [SerializeField]
    float leftTarget, rightTarget;

    void Update()
    {
        float h = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        transform.Translate(Vector2.right * h * speed * Time.deltaTime);

        //if (transform.position.x < leftTarget)
        //    transform.position = new Vector2(leftTarget, transform.position.y);

        //if (transform.position.x > rightTarget)
        //    transform.position = new Vector2(rightTarget, transform.position.y);

        Vector2 temp = transform.position;
        temp.x = Mathf.Clamp(temp.x, leftTarget, rightTarget); 
        transform.position = temp;
    }
}
```

Meanwhile, Unity Hub 3.5.0 has 2022.2.2f1 LTS installed. On the code side, I'm using VS 2022.

I did research on the internet. I made an example with Rigitbody. It just moved down that way. I have examined the problems shared on the Internet, but I have not been able to reach a conclusion. My expectation is to understand the source of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing something, but your code seems overcomplicated for such a siumple task. Just do something like this:

```
float speed;
Rigidbody2D rigidbody;

void Update(){
rigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speed, 0);
}
```

In the inspector, freeze the Rigibody rotation and Y axis movement. Remember to assing speed and rigidbody variables. To clamp the movement, you can just set colliders to the edges of the world or clamp the transform's position.

Comment: this not working  and i do not know why is not working. In addition, i am adding my unity screen.

Answer (score -2):

i tested the code myself, and it does work for me, paddle indeed moves. Maybe you forgot to add the script to your paddle object or didnt set the speed variable in the editor.

Comment: I haven't forgotten what you mentioned. But I still didn't see any results.